# preg_replace EVERYTHING: text and line breaks

Tags: php, regex, line-breaks

I have a text and simply want to remove everything after my first capture. I figured out that I repeat ".*\s*" at least as often as I have line breaks. But I hope there is a more flexible and dry solution for this.

```
$subject = "SomeText()                                  asaas
DFDFDFD

dsdsds

dsdsds";
$pattern = "#\).*\s*.*\s*.*\s*.*#" ; 
$replacement = ")";
$newText = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
Utils_Echo::myEcho($subject);
Utils_Echo::myEcho($newText);


$pattern = "#\)[.\s]*#"; //I hoped something like this would work but it could not figure it out. Can you show me a way?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordered from the fastest to the slowest:

Without regex: *the most obvious*

```
$newText = ( false !== $pos = strpos($subject, ')') ) ? substr($subject, 0, $pos + 1)
                                                      : $subject;
```

With `preg_match`: *take what you want instead of replacing what you don't want*

```
$newText = preg_match('~[^)]*\)~', $subject, $m) ? $m[0] : $subject;
```

With `preg_replace`: *the s modifier allows the dot to match the newline character*

```
$newText = preg_replace('~\).*~s', ')', $subject);
```

Comment: All three answers help me in inproving my skills. Thank you.